# Test bot with Emulator in Authentication scenarios hit POST500directline/conversations/<conversationId>/activities /w sample code

Tags: authentication, testing, botframework, emulation

As title, I follow guide in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Caadv2%2Ccsharp.
I am finished all steps and verified /w succussed until to step "Test the bot using the Emulator".
I try both sample code in

- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication
- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph

then hit same error as below
[http 500 directline/coversations//activities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEWmJ.png)

Comment: Can you try "Test in Web Chat" In the Azure Portal under your Azure Bot resource (the blue cube) and see if it works there?

Comment: it's worked with re-generate a new app key.  but hit new issue with "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'" .   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.UserToken.<GetTokenWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__5.MoveNext()

Comment: Then that means there's a key or a config somewhere in the process that's incorrect.